# Euclidian Distance of Two (Non-traditional) Vectors in Python

Tags: python, out-of-memory, distance

I have two non-traditional vectors and I'd like to compute the Euclidian distance between them.  The vectors are set up as follows:

```
line1 = '2:20 3:20 5:10 6:10 10:20'
line2 = '1:18 2:20 4:10 6:10 8:20 9:10 10:10'
```

For each element, the first number is the location in the vector and the second is the value (e.g., 2:20 means at element 2 in the vector, the value is 20).  So the vector for line1 is (0,20,20,0,10,10,0,0,0,20) and the vector for line2 is (18,20,0,10,0,10,0,20,10,10).

I have written the following program, which works great.  The problem is that I have HUGE vectors and I want to compare them to thousands of other vectors.  My computer starts giving me memory errors when I try to run it like this.  Is there any way to compute the Euclidian distance between two vectors that are set up in this way without actually creating the long vectors (with many 0 entries)?

```
def vec_line(line):
    vector = [0]*10
    datapoints = line.split(' ')
    for d,datapoint in enumerate(datapoints):
        element = int(datapoint.split(':')[0])
        value = float(datapoint.split(':')[1])
        vector[element-1]=value

    npvec = np.array(vector)
    return npvec

vector1 = vec_line(line1)
vector2 = vec_line(line2)

dist = np.linalg.norm(vector1-vector2)
print dist
--> [39.0384425919]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 'non-traditional' vectors are usually called 'sparse vectors' (or in general, 'sparse matrices'). Scipy has [a package](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) to create them and perform algebraic operations on them.

Here is more or less what you want:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix


def parse_sparse_vector(line):
    tokens = line.split()
    indexes = []
    values = []
    for token in tokens:
        index, value = token.split(':')
        index = int(index)
        value = int(value)
        indexes.append(index)
        values.append(value)
    return csr_matrix((values, ([0] * len(indexes), indexes)))

v = parse_sparse_vector(line1)
w = parse_sparse_vector(line2)
dist = v - w
# avoiding a cast to dense matrix:
np.sqrt(dist.dot(dist.T).sum())
## result is 39.038442591886273
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me out.  I didn't know these were called sparse vectors, so that helps a lot.  I'm getting a different Euclidian distance with my code.  I get 39.0384425919.  I'll see if I can figure out where the difference is. Thanks again!

Comment: @myname you are welcome :) check the last version of the snippet, I just figured out how to avoid casting to a dense matrix anywhere.  Also, I can't really say if this will solve all your efficiency needs: doing a lot of pairwise distances is, well, *O(n^2)*

Comment: Just found the difference.  I think you meant to write value = int(value), not value = int(index).  Thanks again!

Comment: I just found the same error and corrected the snippet, and the result.  Now there is only a difference in precision.